# Year not showing up after publisher and location in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

A paper I'm writing requires me to use a custom citation style. The style's similar to the standard Harvard style, so I've decided to tweak the `biblatex-bath` style to my needs.

Among other things, when citing books, the publisher and location must be given as

```
Publisher; Location; Year.
```

I've found the standard `publisher+location+date` bibmacro, defined by biblatex in `bbx/standard.bbx` and decided to overwrite this, as follows:

```latex
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \newunit%
}
```

Publisher and location come out fine with this, but the year is missing. Here is a complete MWE:

```latex
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8
\begin{filecontents*}{biblatextest2.bib}
@Book{Gali2015,
  author    = {Gal{\'\i}, Jordi},
  title     = {Monetary policy, inflation, and the business cycle: an introduction to the new Keynesian framework and its applications},
  year      = {2015},
  edition   = {2},
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  location  = {Princeton and Oxford},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=bath,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\assignrefcontextentries[]{*}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \newunit%
}
\addbibresource{biblatextest2.bib}
\begin{document}
    \noindent Here is a citation. Compare \cite[p.~123]{Gali2015}.
    \appendix
    \newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]%
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image: Example of missing year]

As you can see, the year after the publisher and location is missing. Printing another field there, e.g. `\printfield{title}` rather than `\printfield{year}`, works; the issue is specific to `\printfield{year}`. (Actually, this isn't entirely true: `\printfield{name}` doesn't work either.)

As usual I'd appreciate any help. (Feel free to suggest a completely different solution as well; I'm not hung up on modifying this particular biblatex style, or modifying any specific style at all. If there is a better way of cooking up a custom biblatex style, I'm all ears.)

Comment: With `biblatex` one should never have to use `\cite[p.~123]{Gali2015}`, it is always preferred to write just `\cite[123]{Gali2015}` and let `biblatex` handle the "p."/"pp." business. In case of `biblatex-bath` you lose the space after "p."/"pp.", but you can get it back with `\renewcommand*{\ppspace}{\addnbspace}`

Comment: `\printfield{year}` doesn't work since the `mergedate` settings of `biblatex-bath` issue `\clearfield{year}` near the beginning of the entry, if you try to print the field after that, you don't get to see anything. `\printfield{name}` does not work because `name` is not a known field in the data model, but if you wanted to print a name field like `author` you would have to use `\printnames{author}` for list fields like `publisher` you need `\printlist{publisher}` (as in the redefinition). ...

Comment: ... For `biblatex` the date does not consist of only `year`, so `\usebibmacro{date}` as in David's answer or `\printdate` are *strongly* preferred over a simple `\printfield{year}` (indeed I would say that `\printfield{year}` should be deprecated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the option `mergedate=false` to your `biblatex` options.

I'd probably be inclined to use `\usebibmacro{date}` instead of `\printfield{year}` to be more consistent with the default macro and allow for more flexibility.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{biblatextest2.bib}
@Book{Gali2015,
  author    = {Galí, Jordi},
  title     = {Monetary policy, inflation, and the business cycle: an introduction to the new Keynesian framework and its applications},
  year      = {2015},
  edition   = {2},
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  location  = {Princeton and Oxford},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=bath,mergedate=false,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\assignrefcontextentries[]{*}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit%
}
\addbibresource{biblatextest2.bib}
\begin{document}
    \noindent Here is a citation. Compare \cite[p.~123]{Gali2015}.
    \appendix
    \newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]%
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!

Comment: **@David Purton**: what would be the option, if I wanted to modify the same bibmacro, but for the APA style? I used this solution but `mergedate` is not defined..............

Comment: @Euclides, you should ask a new question with an appropriate minimal worked example. You could link to this question. However, APA style is tightly tied to official SPA style and not always easy to modify.